# Finding close rows by values in two pandas dataframes without iterating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, and I want to do the following:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    lines = df2[(df2['A'] - row['A']).abs() < threshold]
    arr.extend(lines.values)
```

This way is extremely inefficient, how could I do it without row iterating?
I know I can improve iterating with Cython, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: What is `len(df1)`, `len(df2)` and what is the dtype of the `time_0` column?

Answer (score 0):

If `df1` and `df2` share an index then you can create a boolean mask and then index `df2` by it.

```
mask = (df2.A - df1.A.abs()) < threshold
arr = df2[mask]
```